# Is it possible to read files in order of Date Modified?

Tags: excel, vba

My macro will need to read through a very large directory of files and parse data from them. This directory is updated periodically so I am trying to optimize my program to only read files that were added since the last time the program was run.

So far using FileSystemObject it seems I can only read files alphabetically, if I'm not mistaken.

The best solution I have so far is to read all the files every time, create an array containing the file information, sort by DateModified, then open only the files I need. I'm curious to see if I can skip this step by reading files in order of DateModified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunealy its not possible to "not Sort" , you are doing the best way , the process is too slow ? Show the code maybe i can upgrade the code for you

Comment: When a file is modified or created the Archive attribute is set. This used to be used by backup programs but the world has moved on in the last 38 years. Clear the archive attribute on files already processed.

Comment: The FSO does archive attributes. Here's a small program that shows all 19 attributes https://pastebin.com/v2TbfKAS.

Comment: You could get the file names in order by using the **Shell** `Dir` command with the appropriate switches for sorting by the Last Written Date. `dir /A-D /TW /O-D`.  Then feed the first `n` files into the FSO for getting your data.  Or loop through the list until you hit a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

`Shell` does seem to be a good option here - although I haven't compared performance against a `FSO`. You could, for example, consider the `forfiles` command which allows you to retrieve files modified after a specified date?

Some sample code for that would be as follows:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim fileNames As Collection
    Dim path As String
    Dim dat As Date
    Dim file As Variant

    'Set the path and 'find after' date.
    path = "c:\user\documents"
    dat = #1/1/2018#

    'Fetch the files, setting mask as required.
    'This example is fetching all .txt files.
    Set fileNames = GetFilesModifiedAfter(path, dat, "*.txt")

    'Process the list of files.
    If Not fileNames Is Nothing Then
        For Each file In fileNames
            ' ... do stuff here.
            Debug.Print path & "\" & file
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Private Function GetFilesModifiedAfter( _
    path As String, _
    after As Date, _
    Optional mask As String) As Collection

    Dim cmd As String
    Dim piped() As String
    Dim result As Collection
    Dim i As Long

    'Build the command string.
    'Date must be formatted as MM/DD/YYYY.
    cmd = "cmd.exe /s /c forfiles /p " & _
        """" & path & """" & _
        " /d +" & Format(after, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    'Add the mask if passed-in.
    If mask <> vbNullString Then cmd = cmd & " /m " & mask

    'Execute the command and split by /r/n.
    piped = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(cmd).StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)

    'Leave if nothing is returned.
    If UBound(piped) = -1 Then Exit Function

    'Poplate the result collection,
    'and remove the leading and trailing inverted commas.
    Set result = New Collection
    For i = 0 To UBound(piped)
        If Len(piped(i)) > 2 Then
            result.Add Mid(piped(i), 2, Len(piped(i)) - 2)
        End If
    Next

    'Return the result collection.
    Set GetFilesModifiedAfter = result
End Function
```

---

Update

I've just done some testing and it seems `FSO` is quicker, certainly on Folders containing fewer than 100 files. It'd be interesting to run this on really large folders (say a thousand files) as instinctively I feel `Shell` might have a performance advantage. However, for now, here's the `FSO` version:

```
Private Function GetFilesModifiedAfter2( _
    path As String, _
    after As Date, _
    mask As String) As Collection

    Dim fso As Object, file As Object
    Dim result As Collection

    'Instance of objects.
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set result = New Collection

    'Iterate the files and test date last modified property.
    For Each file In fso.GetFolder(path & "\").Files
        If file.Name Like mask And file.DateLastModified > after Then
            result.Add file.Name
        End If
    Next

    'Return the result collection.
    Set GetFilesModifiedAfter2 = result
End Function
```